# JQuery - Select option

Tags: jquery

I have 2 buttons that fire the same form which appears over the page. I would like a dropdown option to change depending on which button is fired.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var settings = $(this).attr('rel');
$("select[@name='menu'] option[@value='"+settings+"']").attr("selected","selected");
```

Error

> Error: uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:[@value='footer']

Comment: It should have been [value='footer'], not [@value='footer']

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
$("select[name='menu']").val($(this).attr('rel'));
```

Using [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is a much quicker way...but your error is occuring because the `@` was removed from [attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) in [jQuery 1.3](http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.3#Upgrading), it's just `[name='menu']` and `[value='myValue']` now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I couldn't work out why it wasn't working. The article I was following is obviously a little out of date. I will tick the answer in 12 minutes :)